# WPF запуск android приложений

Tags: c#, android, wpf

Какие есть варианты для запуска android приложений (.apk) внутри wpf ?

Т.е. мне необходимо запустить 1/2/10 операционных систем Android, а на них запустить по 1 приложению (.apk) и чтобы всё было сгруппировано в одном окне WPF

Возможно есть какой то вообще другой подход.

Нужно производить различные манипуляции в этих приложениях.

- Клики
- Набор текста
- И т.д.

Comment: То есть вы хотите запустить операционную систему Android внутри WPF приложения? Я все верно понял?

Comment: @aepot да - если это возможно) 2-3-10 операционные системы Android внутри WPF приложения. Я наверняка могу запустить их отдельно, но мне хочется чтобы они были сгруппированы в каком то окне. Вот хочу узнать какие эмуляторы или что то в этом роде, можно так разместить.

Comment: @aepot просто +/- как то знаю WinForms и WPF - поэтому уточняю про WPF. Но если есть что то ещё - где это проще делать c С# + NET Core 3.1, мог бы и другое рассмотреть.

Comment: Есть такое приложение VirtualBox, вроде можно захостить его окно в своём приложении. Сам же VirtualBox является виртуальной машиной, под которой в том числе можно запустить и Android.

Comment: @aepot оО - с VirtualBox как то дело имел очень давно. А вот это что такое ? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужен `пользователький контрол` который можно использовать вставляя его на форму, однако таких контролов насколько я осведомлен не существует и сомневаюсь что существуют легальные способы интеграции нескольких эмуляторов в одно окно.

Однако на `Windows` используя `WIN API` на `С++` можно в одно окно вставить другое (в том числе другую программу) однако это будет чисто визуальное объединение (не функциональное) хотя тем же `WIN API` можно было бы попробовать отсылать на эти окна события клавиатурного ввода и мыши.

**Ниже примерный список нужных функций из `winuser.h` для использования `WIN API`**

Для работы с окнами через `WIN API` нужно получить их индификаторы (`HWND`) можно использовать функцию поиска окон:

```
HWND FindWindowExA(
  HWND   hWndParent, // Рабочий стол имеет HWND = 0 
  HWND   hWndChildAfter,
  LPCSTR lpszClass,
  LPCSTR lpszWindow
);
```

Для надежности поиска HWND рабочего стола лучше использовать:

```
HWND GetDesktopWindow();
```

Вот функция для назначения одному окну другого `родителя` - окна в котором оно будет размещено:

```
HWND SetParent(
  HWND hWndChild,
  HWND hWndNewParent
);
```

Далее нужно спозиционировать встроенное окно в определенном месте относительно верхнего левого угла родительского окна:

```
BOOL SetWindowPos(
  HWND hWnd,
  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  int  X,
  int  Y,
  int  cx,
  int  cy,
  UINT uFlags
);
```

Для взаимодействия с окнами (отсылки им событий мыши и клавиатуры):

```
UINT SendInput(
  UINT    cInputs,
  LPINPUT pInputs,
  int     cbSize
);
```

пример использования:

```
//**********************************************************************
//
// Посылает сообщение о нажатии Win + D чтобы свернуть все окна и показать
// рабочий стол. 
//
//**********************************************************************
void ShowDesktop()
{
    OutputString(L"Sending 'Win-D'\r\n");
    INPUT inputs[4] = {};
    ZeroMemory(inputs, sizeof(inputs));

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_LWIN;
   
    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_D;

    inputs[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[2].ki.wVk = VK_D;
    inputs[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    inputs[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[3].ki.wVk = VK_LWIN;
    inputs[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    UINT uSent = SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    if (uSent != ARRAYSIZE(inputs))
    {
        OutputString(L"Произошла ошибка: 0x%x\n", HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Просто ремарка, есть готовая C# обертка вокруг `SendInput` - NuGet пакет `InputSimulator`. Так же стоит пояснить, что все примеры кода на C++.

Comment: Ссылка в тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248869/373567

Comment: @aepot, спасибо добавил упоминание C++, насчет `InputSimulator` как я понял он для C# т.е. нужно будет писать либо библиотеку для работы либо каким-то образом связывать С++  и С# поэтому - на усмотрение автора вопроса.

Comment: насколько я понял, автор ожидает решение именно для дотнета, а не для плюсов, судя по тегам.

Comment: @aepot cудя по комментариям автора под вопросом он `мог бы и другое рассмотреть`, мой ответ основан на личном опыте - на шарпах я такого не делал, а делал подобное очень давно тогда еще не было .NET

Comment: Спасибо хоть за какой то ответ! Постараюсь разобраться.