# Не отправляются сообщения окну WinApi

Tags: c#, winapi

Вопрос такой. Есть 2 ноутбука. Есть код, отправляющий сообщения стороннему окну. Все писалось по Spy++. Код стандартный

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, (IntPtr)0x00000000, MakeLParam(x, y));
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON, MakeLParam(x, y));
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)0x00000000, MakeLParam(x, y));
```

Так вот на одном ноутбуке он срабатывает в это окно. А на другом - нет. Даже в Spy++ я на одном сообщения свои вижу, а на другом  - вообще тишина.
Окно точно видит, перед нажатием я окно программно нахожу и активирую.

Где искать причины?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мистика. У меня тоже бывает - вчера работало, сегодня нет, хотя ни единой строчки кода не менял. Либо предоставленной вами информации недостаточно для выявления проблемы. Вам в свернутое окно надо кликать? Зачем именно сообщениями делаете? Это DirectX приложение, игра? Винда одинаковая? Запускать от имени адмиристратора пробовали?

Comment: @aepot Это игра. Винда идентичная. Кликаю в развернутое активное окно. Сообщения - это единственное, что у меня сработало на одной машине.

Comment: Если надо в активное окно кликать - используйте стандартные методы ввода - `mouse_event` или `SendInput`. Второе рекомендуется, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248869/373567). Сообщения по идее вообще не должны работать в DirectX игре.

Comment: @aepot На первой машине ваш код тоже кликает, но настолько странно, что я не понимаю, откуда он берет эти корды.... Они даже логике не поддаются.. Я даю на клик (900, 166), он кликает на (1535, 318). (473, 61) - (871, 150). Никаких пропорций я насчитать не смогла

Comment: 4к монитор? Масштабирование логических и физических пикселей тоже можно из winapi получить. Но это уже другая задача. И координаты от угла монитора, а не от угла окна приложения задавать следует. Где-то у меня тоже валялось решение этой задачи.

Comment: Да, проблему с кордами решила. А вот то что вашим способом тоже  на первом кликает, а на втором по-прежнему нет - вот это все еще максимально странно для меня...

Comment: Возможно проблема в правах пользователя в системе. Запустите от админа. Либо игра запущена от админа, а приложение нет, в общем, копать куда-то туда.

Comment: Ни запуск всего от админа, ни танцы с бубном не помогают.. (

Comment: Антивирусы, прочее запущенное ПО. Должно же хоть что-то различаться.

Comment: Кстати, вы проверяли возвращаемое значение из SendInput? Все ли инпуты ушли в систему?